# metro ui css in asp.net 5 mvc 6

Tags: css, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to use the metro ui css styling under ASP.NET 5 and MVC 6 in VS2015. I have included it via Nuget in my project but am unsure what references I need to set up and where in order to access the libraries. I have a feeling it should be included in the _Layout.cshtml file but do not know how to refer to it. There are entries in there for Bootstrap already but these are stored in folders in the Project:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap-touch-carousel/dist/css/bootstrap-touch-carousel.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
```

Thanks

Comment: Which packages have you used for this? They should add some css somewhere in your project structure.

Comment: Like I said I included them via the Nuget management interface in VS2015 but cannot find them anywhere in the Project....

Comment: I understand that, but which exact nuget package did you use?

Comment: Sorry, I installed Metro-UI-CSS 2.0.31.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ASP.NET 5 works differently with their project structure and files it is generally advised, when actually adding 'content' type packages like this, to look on Bower for it.

Bower is very comparable to Nuget, only it deals with CSS and Javascript libraries, for example jQuery and Bootstrap will be found there.

To get your package into your project, either manually open the bower.json in your Visual Studio (it will automatically fetch changes) and specify your package, or if you want a more streamlined approach like the NuGet Package Manager, right click on your project, select Manage Bower Packages... and search for metro-ui-css. This will load the exact same stuff as the Nuget package, only via Bower.

Docs here: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/bower.html

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get the Metro packages!

Comment: Unfortunately however I am still not able to refer to them in any of my Views: any idea what syntax in what file I should use to do that please?

Comment: If they're located in the libs folder, which I'd assume, it should be something like in your first post, for example ~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css. Try to see in your browser if you can reach the file with your path. If you can't figure it out please post a picture of your wwwroot with the folders opened for metro, plus the part of your html where you try to reference them.